# API call - JSON wanted as a response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have a DynamoDB, which holds users names, id etc.

I want to display these as JSON. However, I am currently having an absolute nightmare.

```py
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = client.Table('HelloWorldDatabase')

    #get item by ID
    
    
    response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr('ID').gt('0')
    )
    items = response['Items']

   
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(items)
    }
```

however, what display when i hit the API invoked URL is: all the users inside the body, as an object. Not as an array.

The code i have in my html reads an array using javascript, and on the click of a button displays all the users.

In developer mode i have received this error, but i believe this is the error because there is no ARRAY to read on the page. Once an array of each user is available on the result, this im assuming this would resolve.

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function**

JS inside html page hosted on AMPLIFY

```
    document.getElementById('getPosts').addEventListener('click', getPosts);



    function getPosts(){
      fetch('<invoked url api gateway>')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        let output = '<h2 class="mb-4">DynamoDB</h2>';
        data.forEach(function(post){
          console.log(post);
          output += `
            <div class="card card-body mb-3">
              <h3>${post.ID}</h3>
              <p>${post.Name}</p>
              <p>${post.LatestGreetingTime}</p>
              <p>${post.website}</p>

            </div>
          `;
        });
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
      });
    }

   
  </script>
```

Literally cant be this hard to print out a list of arrays of each user?

thank you :)

Comment: If you `console.log(data)`, what does it look like?

Comment: I placed this inside my javascript.

all-students.html:117 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
    at all-students.html:117
(anonymous) @ all-students.html:117
Promise.then (async)
getPosts @ all-students.html:115

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking you what's actually in `data`.

Comment: honestly, not sure. I followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oive66jrwBs) - if i find a page that is a json output, it will display it correctly -which leads me to think that my page just needs that json output from my dynamodb/api gateway/lambda

Comment: Well you need to find out. This is pretty basic debugging. Is the Lambda function actually sending the JSON response that you expect? Is your client-side fetch actually receiving the JSON response that you expect?

Comment: correct yeah; when i hit the invoked URL - i expect there to be 5 JSON items. I can then link the invoked URL to the js code and on click it will place them on the page for the user.

Comment: when running a test via api gateway, this is the response (correct user details of 1 user)

 {
      "ID": "3",
      "LatestGreetingTime": "Sun, 27 Jun 2021 15:19:11 +0000",
      "Name": "Kieran  Clayton"
    }

Comment: That response (a single JSON object) doesn't seem to match the code you've shown (which returns an array of items, even if there is actually only one item in the response from scan). Print out the scan response in your Lambda. Is `items` an array? Or is the code posted above not the code you're actually running?

Comment: That is 1 response from dynamodb, i have say 5 users in there. This is just one response from it. I can get all 5 users to display on the screen, but they dont display as an array, and are all inside the "body"

Comment: I think you're saying that in your Lambda, `items` is (correctly) an array, yes? Going back to my very first comment, what does `console.log(data)` on the client yield?

Comment: apologies, but i have absolutely no idea. I wouldn't even know the first place to look in to order to debug that myself.

Comment: If you're unable to debug, I suggest that you find someone who can debug it for you. Talk to whoever created the webapp and/or the Lambda function.